# Apache url rewrite `-` to `_`

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

how to use url rewrite, change url from

`http://www.mydomain.com/this-is-a-new-article`

to

`http://www.mydomain.com/this_is_a_new_article`?

Use:

`# RewriteRule ^(.+?)-(.+?)$ (.+?)_(.+?) [R=301,L,NE]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sedhyphen.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -u 's/-/_/g'
```

httpd conf:

```
RewriteMap sed-hyphen prg:sedhyphen.sh
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${sed-hyphen:$1} [L]
```

Make sure that sedhyphen.sh is set executable.

Taken from - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105009/mod-rewrite-replace-all-underscore-with-hyphen (They were converting the opposite way)

You could also do something like this but it is less dynamic

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*)-(.*)-(.*)/ http://website.com$1_$2_$3/ [R=301]

From:
http://yoast.com/apache-rewrite-dash-underscore/